# How to get an object of java class from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a result jsp page, which print the string variable of java class. 
Can someone give me any idea.

I am using simple httpServlet as action class.

```
Class A 
{  
String name;  
public void setName()
{  
   this.name = callMethod(); // somehow it assigns the value. Nothing to do with problem  
}  
}
```

**Result.jsp**

Here i need to print the current value of String

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the servlet, at the end, forwards the request to the JSP.

You should store the objects you want to use in the JSP in the request, as an attribute.

In the action class / servlet :

```
request.setAttribute("name", name);
```

In the JSP (using the JSTL) :

```
<c:out value="${name}"/> or <c:out value="${requestScope.name}"/>
```

Comment: @JB hww are you referencing the java bean instance.you are setting in request , for every request u are creating a new instance.

Comment: @Suresh: Your example overrides any instance which is set by the servlet. Further, in a well designed MVC oriented webapp, the `jsp:useBean` has no place.

Comment: @BalusC i know that useBean creates instance every time, according to JBNzet's code, where is he referring the instance from ?

Comment: @BalusC: you mean to say attribute name is referring to Class A.

Comment: @Balusc i want to know where is he getting the object reference from ( i.e.who is setting the name variable?)

Comment: @Suresh: The 1st line of JB's answer is setting it. The 2nd line is getting it. The servlet hello world in the linked wiki page does also the same. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @BalusC: yes he is setting it,but how where he instantiates Class A and assigning it to name?

Comment: @Suresh: Just in the servlet. The OP told he was using servlet.

Comment: @BalusC: so he creates instance of ClassA from servlet for every request  or he does he creates the instance in the init() method of servlet.

Comment: @Suresh: Once again: learn Servlets. It seems that you know nothing about servlets. Please don't hijack other's posts for this. Press `Ask Question` button on right top if you stucks :)

Comment: @BalusC sorry you didnt understand , what i was tryin to explain u

Comment: @Suresh: You didn't explain anything. You keep asking questions because of your ignorance about servlets. This is not the right place to do this. Press `Ask Question` button on right top. I'm happy to answer this all, but just not here in comments. This is simply abuse.

Comment: @BalusC: the above comments seems to you that iam asking a questions?. that's why i said u didn't understand.i was asking OP , how he instantiates ClassA per request or servlet init.

Comment: @Suresh: Then it was your incorrect use of `@comment` replies. Can happen. Be careful in the future. Learn here how it works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 0):

In jsp at the top u need to place

```
<jsp:useBean id= "classAReference" scope= "page" class= "A"  > </jsp:useBean>
```

In the body you need to place
    Please dont use **scriplets**,i used for example ,need to use **JSTL**

```
 ECHO <jsp:getProperty name="classAReference" property="name"/> 

<c:out value='${pageScope.classAReference.name}'/>
```

Comment: This will create a new instance of the class A. It won't reuse the A instance where the name is stored. Moreover, jsp:xxx tags are obsolete and should almost never be used anymore, as well as scriptlets.