# Access Arrays inside Java Objects

Tags: arrays, jsp, foreach, javabeans

How do I obtain values of an array that is located inside a java object in a jsp page?

I have set an object attribute so that in the jsp page I can call the object like so

```
${obj.property}
```

My question is how would I obtain property String [] example from Object obj?

```
<c:forEach var="prop" items="${obj.example}">
                <td>${prop}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

I get Errors that tell me the class obj.Obj does not have the property property 'example'
and obviously I don't get the data out.

Actual errors:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'roommate.Roommate' does not have the property 'favProfessors'.

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'roommate.Roommate' does not have the property 'favProfessors'

And my actual class:

```
    package roommate;

public class Roommate{
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname; 
    public String gender;
    public String place;
    public String[] favProfessors;





public Roommate(String fname, String lname, String roommateGender, String hangout,String[] professors) {
        firstname= fname;
        lastname= lname;
        gender= roommateGender;
        place= hangout;
        favProfessors= professors;

    }



    public String getFirstname() 
    { 
        return firstname; 

    }

    public void setFirstname(String newFirstname) 
    {
        this.firstname = newFirstname; 
    }
    public String getLastname() 
    { 
        return lastname; 

    }
    public void setLastname(String newLastname) 
    {
        this.lastname = newLastname; 
    }
     public String getGender() 
    { 
        return gender; 

    }
    public void setGender(String newGender) 
    {
        this.gender = newGender; 
    }
    public String getHangout() 
    { 
        return place; 

    }
    public void setHangout(String newPlace) 
    {
        this.place = newPlace; 
    }
    public String[] getProfessors() 
    { 
        return favProfessors; 

    }
    public void setProfessors(final String[] newfavProfessors) 
    {
        this.favProfessors = newfavProfessors; 
    }

    public void addRoommate(String fname, String lname, String roommateGender, String hangout,String[] professors)
    {

    }

}
```

I create the object in my servlet as well ass the Atrribute

```
String [] profArray = request.getParameterValues("professor");

        Roommate roommate= new Roommate(
                session.getAttribute("fname").toString(),
                session.getAttribute("lname").toString(), 
                session.getAttribute("gender").toString(),
                session.getAttribute("hangout").toString(),
                profArray);


         session.setAttribute("roommate",roommate);
```

I asked this earlier but did not receive a clear answer. I think my issue is in pulling the data  out in the jsp alone in my forEach that I mentioned at the top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088625/how-to-get-an-object-of-java-class-from-jsp

Comment: In future questions, do not show obfuscated code as long as you don't understand what's going on and have not executed/tested it. Instead show the **real** code which you have really executed/tested yourself. Your previous question contained *correct* code. Do not ask overgeneralized questions. Ask a question about your real and concrete problem with real and concrete code.

Comment: no actually my previous question was not the real code.. the last two code snippets in this question is the real code

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's exactly why I said you to **not** do that anymore. You see, your previous question got downvoted and was unansweable because the code was correct!

Comment: interesting.. then i am completely  lost as to why I cant seem to pull this data out. I can do it just fine by setting an Attribute in the servlet and using a forloop in the jsp.. but can't seem to get it through the object

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, I changed the getter method name and In my forEach the items becomes something like this : [Ljava.lang.String;@1733b79 in firebug (binary?) and does not display anything

Comment: That's the default `toString()` presentation of a `String[]`. Do a `System.out.println(array)`, you'll see that it's exactly that value. If you want to show the array's contents as a string, then you should actually be printing `Arrays.toString(array)` instead of `array.toString()`. In JSP, that can happen when you printed `${roommates.favProfessors}` plain vanilla instead of iterating over it in `<c:forEach>`. This is by the way a completely different problem than you initially asked. Even more, you've already posted the right `<c:forEach>` syntax yourself.

Comment: BalusC - thank you for you time/effort it it ended up being that I did not include the taglib :/

Answer (score 0):

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'roommate.Roommate' does not have the property 'favProfessors'

Java is right. You do not have a `getFavProfessors()` method in that class. It's instead the following:

```
public String[] getProfessors() 
{ 
    return favProfessors; 

}
```

You have 2 options: use `${roommate.professors}` instead, or fix the getter method name to be `getFavProfessors()`.

In contrary to what most starters think, [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) does not access private properties directly. EL just calls the public getter/setter methods according the [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138795.html). The real private property behind it can have a completely different name or even not exist at all.